# How to parse existing functions to a Python class definition?

Tags: python, object-oriented, quantum-computing

I have an implementation of a Quantum CNN on the MNIST dataset but right now, the code is just a bunch of standalone functions that call one another:

```
# Dataset preparation
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Normalizing the data between range of 0 and 1
x_train = x_train[..., np.newaxis] / 255.0
x_test = x_test[..., np.newaxis] / 255.0

# This function allows for the classification of all 10 classes (0-9) as 0 or 1 respectively.
# If the output is true during inferencing, it will be 1. Otherwise 0.
def filter(x, y):
    ...

    return x, y


x_train, y_train = filter(x_train, y_train)
x_test, y_test = filter(x_test, y_test)

# The images in the MNIST dataset as 28x28. Due to the limitations of the
# qubit amount, we have to reduce the image size to 6x6.
x_train_small = tf.image.resize(x_train, (6, 6)).numpy()
x_test_small = tf.image.resize(x_test, (6, 6)).numpy()


# This function changes the labels to -1.0 and 1.0 to be able to use in a Parametrized # Quantum Circuit layer
def convert_label(y):
    return ...


y_train_converted = [convert_label(y) for y in y_train]
y_test_converted = [convert_label(y) for y in y_test]

# Selecting a subset for training from our minimized images
x_train_small_sub = x_train_small[:300]
x_test_small_sub = x_test_small[:100]

y_train_sub = y_train_converted[:300]
y_test_sub = y_test_converted[:100]


# Building the Quantum Model
def one_qubit_unitary(bit, symbols):
    # This circuit enacts a rotation of Bloch sphere about the X, Y and Z axis, that depends on the values in 'symbols'
    return ...


def two_qubit_unitary(bits, symbols):
    ...

    return ...


bits = cirq.GridQubit.rect(4, 4)
for i, j in zip(bits[0::2], bits[1::2]):
    print(i, j)


def conv_circuit(bits, symbols):
    ...

    return ...

readout_operators = cirq.Z(bits[-1])


@tf.function
def custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    ...


def create_model(qubits):
    ...


qubits36 = cirq.GridQubit.rect(4, 4)

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string), tfq.layers.PQC(create_model(qubits36), readout_operators)])


def encode_circuit_16(values):
    ...


x_train_16 = [encode_circuit_16(x) for x in x_train_small_sub]
x_test_16 = [encode_circuit_16(x) for x in x_test_small_sub]

x_train_tensor_16 = tfq.convert_to_tensor(x_train_16)
x_test_tensor_16 = tfq.convert_to_tensor(x_test_16)


@tf.function
def custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    ...


def hinge_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    ...

    return ...
```

This is where the model is being trained:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.losses.Hinge(), metrics=[hinge_accuracy])

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(x=x_train_tensor_16, y=np.asarray(y_train_sub), batch_size=16, epochs=25, verbose=1,validation_data=(x_test_tensor_16, np.asarray(y_test_sub)))

qcnn_results = model.evaluate(x_test_tensor_16, np.asarray(y_test_sub))

qcnn_accuracy = qcnn_results[1]
print(qcnn_accuracy)
```

The code works well but I want to use proper OOP practices with Python. How can I add everything here in a proper class with its appropriate constructor? How many classes should I divide this entire code base into?